# PCA for features selection in Python's sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, feature-selection

Have a question about PCA method in selecting important features.

So, let's assume that there is a dataset with 15 features and I want to understand the 5 most important features from the whole set. What I'm doing:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

x=scale(df)

pca = PCA(n_components=5)
df_t = pca.fit_transform(df)

df_t.explained_variance_ratio_
```

So finally I have an array with 5 explained variance. But for what features does it go? For first five from the dataset? Or for the most important? And if so, how can I understand the names of these features?

Comment: I'm not an expert but feature reduction and feature selection are different things, from what I know about PCA, it's not a tool to select features but to create new ones from the ones you have, trying to keep the maximum variance by combining those that are correlated (so your 5 are somehow the 15). Again, I can be wrong, http://stats.stackexchange.com/ is probably more suited to questions like this.

Comment: The output of explained_variance_ratio_ are not original features, but principal components. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369006/finding-the-dimension-with-highest-variance-using-scikit-learn-pca

Comment: Thanks, all clear!